# How to add an image in React Ag-Grid cell by using an image url

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

How to render an **image** in **React Ag-Grid cell**. Here I am trying to display data of covid-19 by using Ag-Grid. The images of country flags should be be display as first column. I am fetching data from a public API (https://corona.lmao.ninja/v2/countries). We will get the URLs of flags from the fetched data.

This is a sample array of object data from the public API,

`[{"updated":1627371592714,"country":"Afghanistan","countryInfo":{"_id":4,"iso2":"AF","iso3":"AFG","lat":33,"long":65,"flag":"https://disease.sh/assets/img/flags/af.png"},"cases":145008,"todayCases":0,"deaths":6515,"todayDeaths":0,"recovered":93641,"todayRecovered":0,"active":44852,"critical":1124,"casesPerOneMillion":3638,"deathsPerOneMillion":163,"tests":693751,"testsPerOneMillion":17405,"population":39859479,"continent":"Asia","oneCasePerPeople":275,"oneDeathPerPeople":6118,"oneTestPerPeople":57,"activePerOneMillion":1125.25,"recoveredPerOneMillion":2349.28,"criticalPerOneMillion":28.2}]`

The flag URL contains inside **countryInfo->flag.**

Here is my React code for rendering.

````
```componentDidMount() {
    axios.get("https://corona.lmao.ninja/v2/countries").then(response => {
        this.setState({worldData:response.data });
    });

}
render() {
    var temp_arr=[];
    let keys = Object.keys(this.state.worldData);
    keys.map((key,itm)=>{
      temp_arr.push(this.state.worldData[key]);
    })
    return (
        <div className="ag-theme-alpine" style={{weight:800,height:800}}>
                
           <AgGridReact rowData={temp_arr} rowSelection="multiple">

              //Flag image should be added here

             <AgGridColumn field="country" sortable={ true } filter={ true } ></AgGridColumn>
             <AgGridColumn field="cases" sortable={ true } filter={ true }></AgGridColumn>
             <AgGridColumn field="active" sortable={ true } filter={ true }></AgGridColumn>
             <AgGridColumn field="recovered" sortable={ true } filter={ true }></AgGridColumn>
             <AgGridColumn field="deaths" sortable={ true } filter={ true }></AgGridColumn>
           </AgGridReact>
                 
            </div>
    );}```
````

Answer (score 0):

Use a [Cell Renderer](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-grid/component-cell-renderer/) to render images on a column, see the following [example in the documentation](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-grid/component-cell-renderer/#example-cell-renderer)